# Prove that a holomorphic function bounded by $1/\sqrt{|z|}$ on the pierced unit disc has a holomorphic continuation on the whole disc

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

Let $\mathbb{D^*}=\left\{z∈C∣0<|z|<1\right\}$ be the pierced unit disc, $f\in \text{Hol}(\mathbb{D^*})$.

For every $z\in\mathbb{D^*}$:$$|f(z)|\leq\frac{1}{\sqrt{|z|}}$$

Prove that there exists a function $g\in \text{Hol}(\mathbb{D^*})$ such that $g(z)=f(z)$ for every $z∈\mathbb{D*}$.

I started by finding the residue of $f$ at $0$:

$$
|2i\pi\cdot \text{res}_0(f)|=\left|\int_{|z|=\frac{1}{2}}f(z)dz\right|\leq\int_{|z|=\frac{1}{2}}|f(z)|dz\leq\int_{|z|=\frac{1}{2}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{|z|}}dz=0.
$$

Where last equation follows from substituting $z=\frac{1}{2}e^{i\theta}$.

From this follows that $\text{res}_0(f)=0$.

Does that prove that $f$ can be continued holomorphically on $\mathbb{D}$?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it does not. Residue being $0$ does not imply that the function has  a removable singularity (Eg. $\frac 1 {z^{2}}$).

$zf(z)$ is bounded and it tends to $0$ s $z \to 0$. Hence, there is a holomorphic function $h$ such that $zf(z)=h(z)$ and $h(0)=0$. Since $h(z)=0$ we can write $h(z)=zg(z)$ for some holomorphic function $g$. Can you finish?

Comment: I think I can! From this result we get that 0 is a pole of a maximal order 1 of g, but the residue is 0, and therefore g is holomorphic on the disc and equal to f. Right?

Comment: @KirillSm notice that $g(z)$ is holomorphic by the way it was defined. do you know the fact that if a holomorphic function $f(z)$ has a zero at $a$ than there exists a holomorphic function $g(z)$ such that $f(z)=(z-a)g(z)$?